# How to plot boundary and centroids on video frames called inside step() function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, matlab-cvst

I am calling some images inside a `for` loop and then doing some processing on those images. After that, I am using the `step` function to display those frames and their masks inside a video player. How can I add a boundary to an object inside the mask image?  Also, how can I make the boundary thicker and plot the centroids of each blob in the mask in the mask image? Below is the rough sketch of the code.

```
   videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer();
   maskPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer();
  for ii = 1:nfiles
  filenameii = [............]
  frame= imread(filenameii);
  mask = dOB(frame,BackgroundImg);
% some processing on the images
  mask= bwareaopen(mask,27);
  boundaries = bwboundaries(mask,'noholes');
  B=boundaries{1};
  Centroid = regionprops(mask,'centroid');
  Centroids = cat(1, Centroid.Centroid);
  plot(B(:,2),B(:,1),'g','LineWidth',3);
  plot(Centroids(:,1), Centroids(:,2), 'r+', 'MarkerSize', 10);  step(videoPlayer,frame);
  step(maskPlayer, mask);
```

P.S: I know how to display it on a figure using `hold on` but I would like this done directly on the image before displaying it in the video player.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply paint the pixels on the mask first before displaying it in the video player.  What you have does work, but it will plot the boundary inside the figure for the mask player.  Therefore, take your boundaries that you detected from `bwboundaries`, create linear indices from these coordinates and set the values in your image to white.  What may be even simpler is to take your mask that you detected and use [`bwperim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwperim.html) to automatically produce a mask that contains the boundaries of the blobs.  I also see that you are filling in the holes of the mask, so you can use [`imfill`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) directly on the output of your post-processing so that it gives you an image instead of coordinates. You would then use this mask to directly index into your image and set the coordinates of the boundaries of the blob to your desired colour.  If you desire to make the perimeter thicker, a simple image dilation with [`imdilate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) using the appropriately sized square structuring element will help.  Simply define the size of the neighbourhood of this structuring element to be the thickness of the perimeter that you desire.  Finally, if you want to insert the centroids into the mask and since you have the MATLAB Computer Vision System Toolbox, use the [`insertMarker`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertmarker.html) function so that you can use a set of points for each centroid and put them directly in the image. However, you must be sure to change the mask from a `logical` to a data type more suitable for images. `uint8` should work. Therefore, cast the image to this type then multiply all nonzero values by 255 to ensure the white colours are maintained in the mask. With `insertMarker`, you want to insert red pluses with a size of 10 so we need to make sure we call `insertMarker` to reflect that.  Also, because you want to have a colour image you will have to make your mask artificially colour and to do this painting individually for each plane for the colour that you want.  Since you want green, this corresponds to the RGB value of `(0,255,0)`.

Therefore, I have modified your code so that it does this.  In addition, I've calculated the centroids of the **filled** mask instead of the original.  We wouldn't want to falsely report the centroids of objects with gaps... unless that's what you're aiming for, but let's assume you're not:

```
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer();
maskPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer();

% New - Specify colour you want
clr = [0 255 0]; % Default is green

% New - Define thickness of the boundaries in pixels.
thickness = 3;

% New - Create structuring element
se = strel('square', thickness);

for ii = 1:nfiles
    filenameii = [............]
    frame = imread(filenameii);
    mask = dOB(frame, BackgroundImg);
    % some processing on the images
    mask = bwareaopen(mask,27);
    %boundaries = bwboundaries(mask,'noholes');
    %B=boundaries{1};

    % New code - fill in the holes
    mask = imfill(mask, 'holes');

    Centroid = regionprops(mask,'centroid');    

    % New code - Create a boundary mask
    mask_p = bwperim(mask, 8);

    % New code - Make the boundaries thicker
    mask_p = imdilate(mask_p, se);

    % New code - create a colour image out of the mask
    [red, green, blue] = deal(255*uint8(mask));

    % Paint the perimeter of the blobs in the desired colour
    red(mask_p) = clr(1); green(mask_p) = clr(2); blue(mask_p) = clr(3);        

    Centroids = cat(1, Centroid.Centroid);
    %plot(B(:,2),B(:,1),'g','LineWidth',3);
    %plot(Centroids(:,1), Centroids(:,2), 'r+', 'MarkerSize', 10);  

    % New - Make mask into RGB image for marker painting and to 
    % show to the user
    mask_p = cat(3, red, green, blue);

    % New - Insert the centroids directly in the mask image
    mask_p = insertMarker(mask_p, Centroids, '+', 'color', 'r', 'size', 10);

    step(videoPlayer, frame);

    % New - Show new mask in the player
    step(maskPlayer, mask_p); 
end
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. This does display a boundary for the blob in the player but it gives shows the original image with boundary not the binary image. I want the boundary to be displayed around the binary image. Can you tell me why it is so?? Also i would like to know what is the difference between using bwboundaries and bwperim.

Comment: Ah, I assumed you wanted it on the original image, not the binary image.  I'll update my post.  The difference between `bwboundaries` and `bwperim` is that `bwboundaries` gives you the perimeters of the blobs as a set of `(x,y)` points.  `bwperim` returns the perimeter of the blobs as an image.  This image is vital for painting the pixels to display this on the figure.

Comment: Thanks alot, its working perfectly now :) . Is it possible to increase the width of the perimeter/Boundary. Also, how to plot the centroid on top of the mask image as it is currently displayed in a separate window.

Comment: @BlueBee Edited.  Good luck.

Comment: The insertMarker gives error "Expected input to be either unit8, unit16...." mask_p is of type logical. How to fix it?

Comment: Thanks alot for helping me out.